# Is it safe to call wait & notify on objects managed by PlayFramework (JPA / Hibernate backend)?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, concurrency, playframework

Suppose I have a simple Model

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class Chart extends Model {

    public String name;

    @Lob
    public String json;
}
```

Now if I were to retrieve an object from the Chart class in a method as follows

```
Chart c = Chart.findById(1L);
doSomethingWithChartAndLetMeKnow(c)
c.wait();
```

Now in this doSomethingWithChartAndLetMeKnow method, once I finish processing, I can call c.notifyAll() and presumably the original method would continue executing.

However, what if a completely different method does the following

```
Chart c = Chart.findById(1L);
c.notifyAll();
```

would the original thread that was waiting on the doSomethingWithChartAndLetMeKnow method be waken up at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would not wake the original thread.

The two requests are handled by separate Sessions.  Entities retrieved in different sessions are not the same Java object.

However, you should check out Play!'s async support instead of using notify() and wait():
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/asynchronous

Comment: Is it a guarantee that entity retrieved in different sessions are different java objects? Or is that what usually happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is wrong:

> Now in this
>   doSomethingWithChartAndLetMeKnow
>   method, once I finish processing, I
>   can call c.notifyAll() and presumably
>   the original method would continue
>   executing.

as you would be calling notify before the wait. Once it got to the wait under the method's call, it would wait for another notify.

That said, I would not recommend using threads in any web application in that way. Check [Akka](http://akka.io/) or some [Actor-model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) library. It will make things simpler.